# ¿Porque me da error el siguiente código?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Buenas, estoy trabajado con `webgrid` en `MVC` en `ASP.NET` en la que genero listas paginadas pero no logro entender porque el siguiente código me genera este error.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ListarConGrid";
    WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(source: ViewBag.datos, rowsPerPage: 3, columnNames: new[] {"IdEmpleado", "Apellido", "Nombre", ""});
 }
```

### ListarConGrid

```
@grid.GetHtml(

    columns: grid.Columns(

      grid.Column("IdEmpleado", "El IdEmpleado"),
      grid.Column("Apellido", "Los Apellidos"),
      grid.Column("Nombre", "El Nombre"),
      grid.Column("",
        header: "Acciones",
        format: @<text>
        @Html.ActionLink("Editar", "Edit", new { id = item.IdEmpleado })
        |
        @Html.ActionLink("Eliminar", "Delete", new { id = item.IdEmpleado })
        </text>
        )
    )
)
```

Cuando ejecuto el siguiente código me sale un error de que la columna `Nombre` no existe, espero me puedan ayudar. Gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Ya comprobaste que en `grid` exista la columna "Nombre"?

Comment: Cuando estoy depurando me salen las columnas creadas debido a esto: columnNames: new [] {"IdEmpleado", "Apellido", "Nombre", ""}

Comment: Como asignas los datos al Viewbag? y Como los mandas a la Vista?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error es debido a que en tu `ViewBag.datos` no contiene la propiedad `Nombre` para que pueda ser enlazada a tu `WebGrid`.

---

Tendrías que implementar de la siguiente manera, por ejemplo:

**Model:**

```
using System;

namespace HelloWorldMvcApp
{
    public class EmpleadoModel
    {
        public int IdEmpleado { get; set; }     
        public string Nombre { get; set; }      
        public string Apellido { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var listaEmpleado = new List<EmpleadoModel>(){
        new EmpleadoModel { IdEmpleado = 1, Nombre = "Nombre 1", Apellido = "Apellido 1" },
        new EmpleadoModel { IdEmpleado = 2, Nombre = "Nombre 2", Apellido = "Apellido 2" }
    };

    ViewBag.datos = listaEmpleado;

    return View();
}
```

**[DEMO](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jzC1Km)**

*PD. No olvides de revisar la DEMO :)*

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda!